# How can I pass raw text as named slot content?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

Here is example:

```html
<script>
    import Component from './Component.svelte'
</script>

<Component>
    <span>How to pass text to slot without span?</span>
</Component>
```

I would like to pass text inside span to "Component" without extra dom element.

Comment: You should not rely on links to compose your question; rather, links should support your content. Please include your code within the question.

Comment: @ConnorLow thank you. I have changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<svelte:fragment slot="named">
  You can pass this text anywhere you want
</svelte:fragment>
```

Learn more: [svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-fragment](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-fragment)